# undefined values from heap in last node of linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

```
[structs.h]

typedef struct s_tok
{
    int     len;
    char    *tok;
    int     type;
    struct  s_tok *next;
} t_tok;

typedef struct s_table{

    char        **paths;
    char        **reserved;
    int         q_c[2];
    t_env       *env;
    t_tok       *token;
} t_table;
```

```
[minishell.c]

#include "./includes/minishell_header.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    t_table     *table;
    char        *cmdline;
    create_shell(envp, &table);
    while(1)
    {
        cmdline = readline(SHELL);
        add_history(cmdline);
        lexical_analyzer(cmdline, table);
        while(table->token != NULL)
        {
            printf("[%s] : %d\n", table->token->tok, table->token->type);
            table->token = table->token->next;
        }
    }
}
```

```
[lex_analyzer.c]

#include "minishell_header.h"

void lexical_analyzer(char *cmdline, t_table *table)
{   
    openquotes(cmdline);
    if(quote_syntax_analyzer(cmdline, table->q_c))
    {
        cmdline = find_replace(cmdline, table->env);
        token_replacment(cmdline, 4, '$');
        token_replacment(cmdline, 3, ' ');
        table->token = tokenization(cmdline);
    }
    else
        printf("%s '%s'\n", QUOTE_SYNTAX_ERR, "\'");
    free(cmdline);
}
```

```
[tokenization.c]

t_tok *tokenization(char *cmdline)
{
    t_tok *tokens;
    int i;

    tokens = NULL;
    i = -1;
    while (cmdline[++i])
    {
        if (cmdline[i] && ft_iswordpart(cmdline[i]))
            add_word(cmdline, &i, &tokens);
        if(cmdline[i] && ft_isspace(cmdline[i]))
            space(cmdline, &i, cmdline[i], &tokens);
        if(cmdline[i] && (cmdline[i] == '\"' || cmdline[i] == '\''))
            expansion(cmdline, &i, cmdline[i], &tokens);
        if (cmdline[i] && (cmdline[i] == '>' || cmdline[i] == '<'))
            redirection(cmdline, &i, cmdline[i], &tokens);
        if (cmdline[i] && cmdline[i] == '|')
            add_pipe(cmdline, &i, cmdline[i], &tokens);
    }
    return (tokens);
}
```

It is my mini bash project. I have a problem but i can't find where is it.

**[minishell-$]** echo "$USER hello "world

When I tried to tokenize this **command** It should return me:

```
[echo] : 4
[] : 3
[user hello ] : 7
[world] : 4
```

But in this case it return me:

```
[echo] : 4
[] : 3
[user hello ] : 7
[world] : 4
[!] : 4
```

I can't understand from where puts the last token?

There is my functions for adding nodes into **t_tok** list.

```
t_tok *new_token(int len, char *token, int type)
{
    t_tok *tok;

    tok = malloc(sizeof(t_tok));
    if(!tok)
        return (NULL);
    tok->len  = len;
    tok->tok  = ft_strdup(token);
    tok->type = type;
    tok->next = NULL;
    return (tok);
}

void    add(t_tok **lst, t_tok *new)
{
    while(*lst)
        lst = &(*lst)->next;
    *lst = new; 
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger or insert test printing in the program.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your code in the `tokenization()` method; you are adding the token regardless of whether `cmdline[i]` is a space:

```
if (cmdline[i])
    add_word(cmdline, &amp;i, &amp;tokens);
```

You should instead test for the presence of a space:

```
if (cmdline[i] &amp;&amp; ft_iswordpart(cmdline[i]))
    add_word(cmdline, &amp;i, &amp;tokens);
```

The way it is now, your code will continue to add the token up to the end of the string.
In your example, `cmdline[i]` is `'\0'` when `add_word()` is called, so the code will read
beyond the end of your buffer and then write beyond the end of your buffer, causing undefined behavior.